# how to add new key and value to angular formgroup?

Tags: angular, typescript

How do I add the associatedAccount as key and value to the formgroup so that when the fromgroup is submitted the value from the request is included . Any idea ? thanks.

cause what I will be adding to the post request is  the modelForm value this.accountService.create(this.modelForm.value) , and I want to add the value from the getAssociatedAccount request. Thanks.

The value of associatedAccount is not Form  but I want it be included on the formgroup as a single object.

something like associatedAccount: this.associatedAccount

#request

```
getAssociatedAccount() {
    this.isInProgress = true;
    this.userService.getUserProfile(this.authService.authUser.nameid)
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => this.isInProgress = false),
      ).subscribe({
        next: (res:any) => {
          if (res.isSuccess) {
            this.associatedAccount = res.data.associatedAccount
          }
        },
        error: err => noop,
        complete: () => noop
      });
  }
```

#model

```
private _createModelForm(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      // id: [this.model.id || 0],
      emailAddress: new FormControl(this.model.emailAddress, [
        Validators.required,
      ]),
      firstName: this.model.firstName,
      roleId: this.model.roleId,
      lastName: this.model.lastName,
      phoneNumber: this.model.phoneNumber,
      companyName: this.model.companyName,
      ssocredentials: this.model.ssocredentials,
      accountId: this.accountId,
      title: this.model.title,
      isSso: [this.model.isSso || []],
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new property when you submit the form (you can use the spread operator) without add a new formControl to the form

```
submit(form)
{
   if (form.valid)
      this.accountService.create({
         ...form.value, //<--all the properties of form.value
         associatedAccount :this.associatedAccount //<--and another one
                    })
}
```

If you want to make it editable, yes you can add using the [addControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#addControl) method

```
   this.form.addControl("associatedAccount",new FormControl(this.associatedAccount))
```

NOTE: You can also create the form with this property and give value to it using [setValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#setValue) (remember, a FormGroup exists by itself. It's not necesary to have a input control)

```
  this.form.get("associatedAccount").setValue(this.associateAccount)
```

NOTE2: Also you can in service, before call to api, get the value before send the value

```
create(data:any){
   this.userService.getUserProfile(this.authService.authUser.nameid)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(res=>{
          if (res.Success){
            const dataSend={...data,res.data.assocciatedAccount}
            return this.httpClient.post(".....",dataSend)
          }
          return of({Success:false,Error:"Can't get associatedAccount"})
        })
        finalize(() => this.isInProgress = false),
      ).subscribe()
}
```